# Flattening nested Observables.subscribe

Tags: javascript, promise, angular, rxjs, observable

I am new to `Observables` with rx.js and I wanted to know how I can flatten the following callback hell:

```
function getdata1 (argument) {
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

function getdata2 (argument) {
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

getdata1.subscribe((data1: any) => {
    console.log("got data one. get data 2 now");
    getdata2.subscribe((data2: any) => {
        console.log("got data one and two here");
    });
});
```

I know if this was Promises, `then()` could have been used to flatten it. But I do not know the equivalent of `then()` in `Observables`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `flatMap` operator with `Observable.forkJoin`:

```
getdata1().flatMap(data1 => {
  return Observable.forkJoin([
    Observable.of(data1);
    getdata2()
  ]);
}).subscribe(result => {
  var data1 = result[0];
  var data2 = result[1];
  (...)
});
```

Comment: Is not there anyway I can chain like `getdata1().then(getdata2).then(complete)` ?

Comment: Yes but you won't have `data1` at the end of the chain... But in fact, it's the same with promises ;-) For something similar to `getdata1().then(getdata2).then(complete)`, simply use: `getdata1().flatMap(data1 => getdata2()).subscribe(...)`